# Terraform pathexpand function doesn't work in a complex project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I am new to terraform, and yet I am tasked with managing a fairly complex project which involves a few acounts and environments, we have a lot of tf files, and a lot of lines in each file. It's obvious there are a few things that are not done in best practice. For example, we have the following configuration for provider:

```
   provider "aws" {
      region    = var.region
      access_key = "my-access-key"
      secret_key = "my-secret-key"
      assume_role {
        role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      }
    }
```

We have hard-coding credentials in the config file! So I decided that I need to replace it something like the following:

```
   provider "aws" {
      region    = var.region
      shared_credentials_file = "/home/jerry/.aws/credentials"
      assume_role {
        role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      }
    }
```

This works well, no problem. As we have a team, so I decided to use pathexpand, so that everyone in the team can use their own credentials:

```
   provider "aws" {
      region    = var.region
      shared_credentials_file = pathexpand("~/.aws/credentials")
      assume_role {
        role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      }
    }
```

However, this doesn't work anymore. I got the following error:

```
Error: The role "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:role/aaaaaaaaaaaaa" cannot be assumed.

  There are a number of possible causes of this - the most common are:
    * The credentials used in order to assume the role are invalid
    * The credentials do not have appropriate permission to assume the role
    * The role ARN is not valid
```

I tried starting a new test project using very simple configuration, it works with pathexpand, no issue. but it just won't work with the (big) project that I have been tasked with.

Maybe there are some configuration somewhere that prohibits the function pathexpand to be used? or there are some environment variables that alter the behaviour? I have been researching this for a whole day and have not been able to find the answer.

Please help, any insights are appreciated!

Comment: Did you check that `~/.aws/credentials` exists and user allowed to assume the role?

Comment: If you are using the SDK typical ways to get credentials then you don't need to specify that at all so you can completely remove the `shared_credentials_file` parameter as this is the default for the SDK anyway. To debug further you should try running `aws sts get-caller-identity` to check that you are assuming your user's credentials via the credentials file and then attempt to assume your role using `aws sts assume-role`. You should then edit your question to include the censored outputs of that.

Comment: @rkm yes, of course, things would work with /home/my_id/.aws/credentials, but not with ~/.aws/credentials.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR The credentials are there, and would work with aws sts assume-role command. The problem seems to be that pathexpand(~/.aws/credentials) fails to expand to the the correct path, how do I do an in-place trace whether pathexpand(~/.aws/credentials) indeed works?

Comment: I can't see why that would fail but as mentioned it's entirely unnecessary. You can just remove the line and rely on the normal credential chain to discover credentials at `~/.aws/credentials` instead.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Removing shared_credentials_file produces the same error.  I also tried setting environment variables, doesn't work either. All these would work in another test of my own project. It's really confusing...

Comment: That sounds like your IAM permissions are setup wrong then. I'd double check that very carefully but I don't think it's something we can solve for you without seeing more of your account.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR it's the same account, credentials and linux server I was using to do the test that works. So I am not sure if this is the IAM permission issue...

Comment: The last thing I'd check is to drop the `assume_role` block and then check the output of the `aws_caller_identity` data source to check that it's loading the credentials you think you should be.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I think I know what is going on... when I run terraform commands, I had to use sudo, so it's possible that ~/.aws/credentials expands to /root/.aws/credentials instead of /home/my-id/.aws/credentials... But I don't know why sudo is needed... if sudo is absent, I would get error like ": Error loading state: AccessDenied: Access Denied"...

Comment: Are you using local state? If so it's because you originally ran it with sudo and created the state file as root.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR no it's stored in S3 backend. Is there any way I can remove this restriction...?

Comment: `sudo chown -R $SUDO_USER:$SUDO_USER .` from your Terraform source code directory would change ownership of everything back to your user and fix your mistake.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR thanks... but this doesn't seem to work... the ownership of the files doesn't seem to be the problem, as none of the files are owned by root

Comment: That `AccessDenied: Access Denied` error sounds like an S3 error, in which case it sounds like you have a `/root/.aws/credentials` which grants access to your S3 bucket and a separate `/home/my-id/.aws/credentials` which grants the access the provider needs, and so unless you're able to merge those in some way the two will be mutually exclusive.